# jQuery: .each() seems to return wrong values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, each

I am working on an HTML-/PHP-/Jquery-App and got some problems with the .each-return-Value of jQuery.

I've got a form that has several input-fieldsets and you can add another fieldset if you need:

```
<input id="plot1_id" type="hidden" value="2">
<input id="plot1_position" type="hidden" value="1">
<textarea id="plot1_txt" class="plot_entries">Entry number 1</textarea>
<input id="plot2_id" value="12">
<input id="plot2_position" type="hidden" value="2">
<textarea id="plot2_txt" class="plot_entries">Entry number 2</textarea>
<input id="plot3_id" value="545">
<input id="plot3_position" type="hidden" value="3">
<textarea id="plot3_txt" class="plot_entries">Entry number 3</textarea>
[etc.]
```

When saved - jQuery uses

```
i=1;
$('.plot_entries').each( function() {
        fieldsetAR.push( fieldsets(
        $('#plot' + i + '_id').val(),
        $('#plot' + i + '_position').val(),
        $('#plot' + i + '_txt').val()
        ) );
        i=i+1;
});
```

to get every input-field seperated to 'save' to an array and push through ajax's .load().

*My Problem:*
I can't get the last entry right! The last or newly added input-element won't be registered as *the last* object within the .each-function.

*For example:*
The last entry returned by the script would be

```
plot2_id = '2'
plot2_txt = 'Entry number 2'
```

instead of the *real* last one (plot3_id & plot3_txt)...

I'm totally confused - hopefully someone can help me out :/

E: Still confused and not solved  :(
Any other idea?

Comment: Check the initial value of variable `i`

Comment: sorry, I didn't mention: `i` is set to one (code updated)

Answer (score 1):

Probably because your `i` starts from 0. Change it to start with 1

```
var i=1;
$('.plot_entries').each( function() {
    fieldsetAR.push( fieldsets(
    $('#plot' + i + '_id').val(),
    $('#plot' + i + '_position').val(),
    $('#plot' + i + '_txt').val()
    ) );
    i=i+1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's index argument instead of preserving the number yourself.

```
$('.plot_entries').each( function(i) {
  ++i;
  fieldsetAR.push( fieldsets(
  $('#plot' + i + '_id').val(),
  $('#plot' + i + '_position').val(),
  $('#plot' + i + '_txt').val()
  ));
});
```

Comment: now still there is a problem with my _new entries_: they're not added to the array ...